# How can I do HTTP POST requests on Pyodide

Tags: python, pyodide

In pyodide,  it is not support the requests module so to fetch the data from api we used open_url and how can we use the api for post the Data using pyodide

Answer (score 7):

**Update: Pyodide v0.21.2**

It is currently [impossible](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/project/roadmap.html#write-http-client-in-terms-of-web-apis) to use the [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) since sockets are not available in Pyodide.

However, you can use JS [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) direct form Python code. To do this, you must import `window` object from `js` module. Here is a live demo:

```js
(async () => { // enable await
  // init pyodide
  let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
  // import window object
  pyodide.runPython('from js import window')
  // fetch json
  let result = await pyodide.runPythonAsync("window.fetch('http://karay.me/truepyxel/test.json')")
  // result is now a response object
  console.log(result)
  // convert response to json
  let data = await result.json()
  console.log(data)
  alert(data.msg)
})() // call the function immediately
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.21.2/full/pyodide.js"></script>
```

More details [here](https://karay.me/2022/07/12/bringing-python-to-the-web.html).

---

**Pyodide v0.15.0**

```js
let python_code = `
from js import window

def fetch():
  window.fetch('http://karay.me/truepyxel/test.json').then(lambda resp: resp.json()).then(lambda jsoh: show_result(jsoh))
  
def show_result(data):
  div = window.document.createElement('div')
  #insert into body as a first child
  window.document.body.prepend(div)
  div.innerHTML=window.JSON.stringify(data)
`

// init environment
languagePluginLoader
// then run Python code
  .then(() => pyodide.runPythonAsync(python_code));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://pyodide-cdn2.iodide.io/v0.15.0/full/pyodide.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick='pyodide.globals.fetch()'>Fetch</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The requests module is currently not supported in pyodide because it relies on sockets which are not implemented in the WebAssembly browser VM.

You can however, make POST calls using Web APIs in pyodide. Below is an example using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

```
from js import XMLHttpRequest, Blob
import json

data = {"a": 1}

req = XMLHttpRequest.new()
req.open("POST", "https://httpbin.org/anything", False)
blob = Blob.new([json.dumps(data)], {type : 'application/json'})
req.send(blob)
str(req.response)
```

In the future it's possible that some of the classical HTTP client modules might be patched to use Web APIs in pyodide (cf [pyodide#140](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide/issues/140)).

Comment: How can I install that `js` module? It's not this one I think https://pypi.org/project/javascript/?

Comment: It's provided by Pyodide, you don't need to install it, it's available by default there. So if you use anything that uses Pyodide: PyScript, JupyterLite etc you will have it.

If you use a different wasm build of Python then this module won't exist, and you will not be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks @rth! Perhaps this question is too broad for a comment here, but if I want to test this code locally, how would I do that? I installed `pyodide` with `pip install pyodide-py`, but that doesn't seem to allow me to `import js`.

Comment: Actually you should install pyodide >=v0.25.0a2, that and later version should just work with requests, so you would no longer need the explicitly import the js module for this functionality. 

About things not being quite identical with installing pyodide-py outside of the browser, yes that's expected and unfortunately a limitation of that apporach

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned we cannot use requests, so you can use javascript fetch to perform the POST operation, the sample snippet will work with pydiode and pyscript (async format), this same code can be written in sync-fashion using `add_done_callback`

```py
import asyncio
from js import console, fetch

async def post_data():
    response = await fetch('http://example.com/test',{'method':'POST'})
    json = await response.json()
    console.log('json', json)
    return json

await post_data()
```

Comment: Which module is that `js`? I don't think it's this one https://pypi.org/project/javascript/ ?

Comment: Given this is in Pyodide, it's the one that enables you to use js from the global scope (ie in the browser/runtime). See here: https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/python-api.html